# What are highest clock frequencies for consumer CPU achieved with extreme cooling?

Tags: cpu, cooling, overclocking, clockspeed

I just read how [the new AMD 7th-gen SoCs can be stably overclocked to 4.8 GHz](http://www.anandtech.com/show/10705/amd-7th-gen-bristol-ridge-and-am4-analysis-a12-9800-b350-a320-chipset) and was reminded of the [5GHz project](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/5-ghz-project,731-13.html), which got a Pentium 4 to a 5225 MHz frequency - more than a decade ago.

Since then there have probably been more impressive frequency records with mainstream consumer CPUs using extreme cooling measures. Who are the current "record holders" in this respect?

Comment: Interesting question but not a good fit for the site.  It is likely to attract a list rather than a definitive answer, which would be hard to post because of the number of variables, and answers will rapidly become outdated.

Comment: This is true, these achievements become outdated almost monthly by people with huge budgets to spend on how far they can push there CPUs.

Comment: The clock frequency has no useful meaning.  It's just a measurement of something that... is useless to measure.  Last gen Pentium 4s were about 3 Ghz +, while a first Gen Core 2 started around 1 Ghz or so.  The Core 2s were 50 to 75% faster than the Pentium 4s.

Comment: This is going to attract a lot of answers that are largely unverifiable and unconstructive and at best any authoritative answer is quickly likely to become out of date. Many answers to this question are likely to begin with "my mate said he saw a bloke who said he met a guy who once heard a rumor about someone who might have ... "

Comment: @Nelson: I never suggested frequency = performance. But it is indeed interesting to see how far the frequency can go up with existing technology when you take away just the heat dissipation factor.

Comment: If the frequency is a useless value, how is seeing a useless value go higher be "interesting"?  Here, XYZ processor has a bajillion giga-mega hertz.

Comment: Sorry, my comment was not accurate.  It's actually just first gen Core processors.  They were less than half the frequency, but actually did things 50-75% faster.  There's a reason all the earlier processors suddenly didn't have their frequency listed.  It's only within the last couple years where you started seeing "2 Ghz" or so again.  It's a freaking useless number.

Comment: @Nelson: It's not useless to know how far you can overclock something; or what's the potential for the manufacturer to increase the frequency, as opposed to making architectural changes.

Comment: Sure it is.  That time can be spent to identify real system bottlenecks instead of chasing a bigger number.  Significant majority of the time the bottleneck is not in the 'hertz' of a computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you're looking for the fasted overclocking achieved I believe the following post will answer your question (and a lot more): https://hwbot.org/benchmark/cpu_frequency/halloffame

The TDLR: overclockers achieved 8.722GHz with a AMD CPU

However if you are simply looking for the clockable limit of a 6700k then your better off googling it. The amount of Ghz you can squeeze out of a chip largely is impacted by your luck and hardware/patience.

--EDIT--
Fixed link

Answer (score -1):

I've seen posts in the 8+ghz range, a buddy of mine got an i7-2600k to 6.5 on a corsair h60 cooler stable as well.